# gem Lazy High Charts - Pie Donut

Tags: highcharts, lazy-evaluation, pie-chart, donut-chart

I'm trying to create a pie donuts, but it does not  work...
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-donut

Controller

```
@chart_teste5 = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"pie", :margin=> [50, 0, 0, 0]})
  f.title({:text => "test"})
  f.subtitle({:text => "Inner circle: Your Permissions, Outer circle: Your Friend Permission"})
  f.series({
     :type => "pie",
     :name => "2008",
     :size => "45%",
     :innerSize => "20%",
     :data => [{ :name => "Firefox", :y => 44.2, :color => "#4572A7" },{ :name => "IE", :y => 46.6, :color => "#AA4643" },{ :name => "Chrome", :y => 3.1, :color => "#89A54E" },{ :name => "Safari", :y => 2.7, :color => "#80699B" },{ :name => "Opera", :y => 2.3, :color => "#3D96AE" },{ :name => "Mozilla", :y => 0.4, :color => "#DB843D" }],
     :dataLabels=> { :enabled => false }
  },{
     :type => "pie",
     :name => "2010",
     :innerSize => "45%",
     :data => [{ :name => "Firefox", :y => 45.0, :color => "#4572A7" },{ :name => "IE", :y => 26.8, :color => "#AA4643" },{ :name => "Chrome", :y => 12.8, :color => "#89A54E" },{ :name => "Safari", :y => 8.5, :color => "#80699B" },{ :name => "Opera", :y => 6.2, :color => "#3D96AE" },{ :name => "Mozilla", :y => 0.2, :color => "#DB843D" }],
     :dataLabels => { :enabled => true }
   })
end
```

View

```
<%= high_chart("my_combine_div", @chart_teste5) %>
```

Error

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Comment: Do you have live demo of it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code working. I hope that this helps

```
@chart_teste5 = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.chart({:defaultSeriesType=>"pie", :margin=> [50, 0, 0, 0]})
  f.title({:text => "test"})
  f.subtitle({:text => "Inner circle: Your Permissions, Outer circle: Your Friend Permission"})
  f.series({
    :type => "pie",
    :name => "2008",
    :size => "45%",
    :innerSize => "20%",
    :data => [{ :name => "Firefox", :y => 44.2, :color => "#4572A7" },{ :name => "IE", :y => 46.6, :color => "#AA4643" },{ :name => "Chrome", :y => 3.1, :color => "#89A54E" },{ :name => "Safari", :y => 2.7, :color => "#80699B" },{ :name => "Opera", :y => 2.3, :color => "#3D96AE" },{ :name => "Mozilla", :y => 0.4, :color => "#DB843D" }],
    :dataLabels=> { :enabled => false }
  }
  )
end
```